# Show that : $\mathcal{X} +\mathcal {Y} =\{X+Y : X\in \mathcal{X} , Y\in\mathcal {Y} \}$ is uniformly integrable

Tags: integration, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and  $\mathcal{X} $, $\mathcal {Y} $ be two uniformly-integrable families on the same probability space $\Omega $.

Show that the following familie is also uniformly integrable: $$ 
\mathcal{X} +\mathcal {Y} =\{X+Y : X\in \mathcal{X} , Y\in\mathcal {Y} \}.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A family $\{X_i\}$ is uniformly integrable iff

a) $\sup_i E|X_i| <\infty$ and

b) for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\int_E |X_i|dP <\epsilon$ whenever $P(E) <\delta$.

Now you only need $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$ to verify that these two properties are satisfied by the sum $\mathcal X +\mathcal Y $

Comment: thank you very much in advance

Comment: @SyaBa In advance??? Upvote and accept the good answers you got on this site. This is the way one thanks people who spent their precious time to help you. Got it now?

Comment: Ok and excuse me